# Can I converting HTML DOM to an Image BUT on specific media query

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to convert HTML DOM to an Image to a specific media query or resolution at least 1920px even the media query on that DOM is detected as Mobile.

A good example is like https://apiflash.com/, but I don't have any idea how to implement it in Javascript a specially on React

Also, I have tried using [dom-to-img](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) but there's no option to render captured DOM on a specific media query, it always follows the media query that is currently active

Any tricks?

Comment: It's true as @Salketer said, BUT you can create your own API like https://apiflash.com/ with NodeJS & ExpressJS using https://github.com/sindresorhus/capture-website, there's an options to capturing a website on specific breakpoint plus it can capture specific an Element to

Comment: thx for the advice @AngularSan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic way, media queries are there to react to the size of the window.

Either size the window correctly or add a class to the body so you can force the same styles as if the media query was at the breakpoint you want.